# Spacing equally sized items in a grid?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for an ie8-compatible way to create the grid:

http://jsbin.com/ihicuz/1/edit

HTML:

```
  <div class="grid">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid{
  background:#DDD;
  width:830px;
  height:830px;
}
.grid>div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  border:1px solid #AAA;
  float:left;
  margin:0 10px 10px 0;
  background:#EEE;
}
.grid>div:nth-child(4n){
  margin-right:0;
}
```

nth-child works (well, ignoring the overflow of the margin bottom) but doesn't work on ie8.

Is there a clean solution to getting equal spacing between these grid items without changing the html markup?

Answer (score 0):

Selectivizr takes care of a lot of IE compatibility issues with CSS3 selectors.

http://selectivizr.com/